# Export table from property drawer in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm learning org-mode now. I'm making a document to keep track of jobs. So each job is a top-level item, and inside it, I have a property drawer along with some other things. In the property drawer, I'm keeping things like the location, contact person and referral source.

```
* Some job
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Location: The Matrix
  :Source: Referral from Oracle
  [...]
  :END:
  [ ... more stuff here ... ]
```

I'm pretty sure that I want to keep these as properties, since I want to be able to search for entries like this:

```
C-c a m 
Match: Source="StackOverflow"
```

But when I go to export this to HTML or ASCII, the properties don't end up anywhere. What I would really like is a **table of key-value pairs** like this:

```
+----------+----------------------+
| Location | The Matrix           |
+----------+----------------------+
| Source   | Referral from Oracle |
+----------+----------------------+
```

which would be located right after the "Some job" heading in the example above. It doesn't matter if it's actually a table; a definition list or whatever would be fine. The only thing I've really tried is

```
#+OPTIONS: d:t
```

... and that did nothing (the properties drawer doesn't count as a drawer for this option maybe?)

Comment: Have a look at [`org-collector.el`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-collector.html).